# can J2ME access camera(image capture) event from N73 device

Tags: java-me, symbian, mmapi

I am working on project where I need to catch the image capture event.
It's for nokia N73 having platform S60 3rd edition.
Is there any possible way using J2ME only (without using symbian).

Description:
J2ME application running in background, on click of capturing image from camera J2ME application initiates and comes in front. Takes the captured image and transfers it to J2ME app and displays on screen.

if not possible using J2ME , Is there any possible way using symbian? can anyone provide tutorial or code snippet?

Thank you.

Regards,
Rajiv

Answer (score 1):

Not possible to access the native camera from J2ME.  You'd need to get the user to start your app first, then access the camera from your app (using JSR 135, [spec here](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr135/), [introduction and examples here](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/mmapioverview/)).  Then you can use the captured image however you wish.

HTH

Comment: I dont want it that way, JSR 135 is there but i dont want the application flaw that way, camera image capture event should start J2ME app? is it possible using symbian? can any one provide solution for that

Answer (score 1):

The N73 in particular has a fairly large hardware limitation when you want to use the camera.

You need to have the user manually open the camera cover before you can use the camera.

This launches the native camera application included in S60.

The user then needs to close that application.

From that point on, J2ME can use the camera, via the mobile media API defined in JSR-135.

If the user reboots the phone, the camera cover needs to be re-opened before J2ME can use the camera again.

You may have better luck using J2ME and JSR-135 to capture images using the front camera on the N73.

I seriously doubt that J2ME would see the user pressing the camera key in `javax.microedition.lcdui.Canvas.keyPressed();`

JSR-135 doesn't really provide a system-wide camera capture event for J2ME.